# With registers fully open I have unbalanced air flow upstairs vs downstairs

Tags: furnace

Upstairs the airflow is OK
Downstairs I have 4 registers. 
Three out of four have very weak air flow while the fourth one is blowing like hell

Is the problem in the furnace or in the air ducts?

Comment: then don't open the 4th fully, close it part way until the airflow equalizes.

Comment: the problem is that the furnace is overheating and the load fan and control limit switch turns the gas off because the air is not leaving the furnace quick enough. Is that possible?

Comment: Are all the returns unobstructed? Is there at least one return for each register?  When was the last time you cleaned/replaced the filter? Is this a new system, or has this problem just started?

Comment: This is an old system ('89) Not sure if it was ever cleaned. The air vents were added later for basement, that might be the reason. Perhaps the unit was sized for upstairs only, I am not sure when the basement was finished. My impression is that it was a more recent job.